# Css not working in the second <div> tag in html

Tags: html, jquery-mobile, themes

I have called 2nd page `<div id=child>` on button click of 1st page `<div id = home>` and used jquery theme in both pages but the problem is in 2nd page there is no theme effect as in 1st page. I have put the css file in same folder and it is giving effect in 1st page and not in 2nd ?

Can any one solve the problem, so that the theme have effect in 2nd page also? Below is my code

```
 <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <title>
        </title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquerybasic/jquerymobilecss.css" />
        <style>
            /* App custom styles */
        </style>

        <script src="jquerybasic/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript">
        </script>
        <script src="jquerybasic/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.js" type="text/javascript">
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#buttonid').click(function() {
                    $('#child').toggle();
                    $('#home').toggle();
                });
                $('#buttonchild').click(function() {
                        $('#child').toggle();
                        $('#home').toggle();
                });

                $('#next').click(function() {
                        $('#home').show();
                        $('#child').hide();
                });
                $('#prev').click(function() {
                        $('#home').hide();
                        $('#child').show();
                });



                $('#nextchild').click(function() {
                        $('#home').show();
                        $('#child').hide();
                });
                $('#prevchild').click(function() {
                        $('#home').hide();
                        $('#child').show();
                });
        });

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div data-role="page" id="home">
            <div data-theme="d" data-role="header">
                <h3>
                    The Grand Bhagavati
                </h3>
                <a data-role="button" id="next"  data-inline="true" data-transition="slide"  >
                    &lt;&lt;
                </a>
                <a data-role="button" id="prev"  data-inline="true" data-transition="fade" >
                    &gt;&gt;
                </a>
            </div>
            <div data-role="content">
                <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                    <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-mini="true">
                        <label for="textinput1">
                            User:
                        </label>
                        <input id="textinput1" type="text" />
                    </fieldset>
                </div>
                <input id="buttonid" data-theme="d" value="Login" type="button"  />
            </div>
            <div data-theme="d" data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" >
                <h3>
                    Page 1
                </h3>

                </div>
        </div>

        <div data-role="page" id="child">
            <div data-theme="d" data-role="header">
                <h3>
                    The Grand Bhagavati
                </h3>
                <a data-role="button" id="nextchild" data-inline="true" data-direction="reverse" data-transition="slide" >
                    &lt;&lt;
                </a>
                <a data-role="button" id="prevchild" data-inline="true" data-direction="reverse" data-transition="fade" >
                    &gt;&gt;
                </a>
            </div>
            <div data-role="content">

                        <label>
                            hi khushbu. welcome...!
                        </label>


                <input id="buttonchild" data-theme="d" value="Login" type="button"  class="ui-btn-hidden" aria-disabled="false" />
            </div>
            <div data-theme="d" data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" >
                <h3>
                    Page 2
                </h3>

                </div>
        </div>

        <script>
            //App custom javascript
        </script>
    </body>
```

Comment: Sorry, just showing the html won't work. Can you provide a link to your site?

Comment: sory but i cant it is just i hav not published it ,this is my learning i m just testing it on my wamp localhost

Comment: Well, then I can only guess. Are you absolutely sure the two pages reference the same CSS file? Are you absolute sure the elements in the two pages have the same classes (or whatever selectors the CSS uses)? Etc.

Comment: You have posted code that you could have turned into a JSFiddle no problem. Here one is: http://jsfiddle.net/KjdjL/. Using this tool in the future will almost certainly improve the quality of answers given in response to your questions. Other developers can actually see your problem exhibit itself and tweak code to see if it fixes the issue.

Comment: Oh, and the reason the CSS isn't being applied to the second div is because you aren't navigating to it the "jQuery Mobile way." When you link between pages using the documented method then jQuery Mobile will automatically initialize every page before it's visible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok boy :)

It seems you've skipped a rather important part of using a new piece of software, reading the documentation.

To navigate between pages you would just place this in the `href` attribute for the link:

```
<a data-role="button" href="#child">...</a>
```

And jQuery Mobile will handle the transition to the next pseudo-page. Here is the documentation for `Linking Pages`: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/docs/pages/page-links.html

If you want to do this programatically then you can use `$.mobile.changePage()` which is what gets used internally. The advantage to manually calling this function (say in a `click` event handler for a button) is that you can specify non-default options for the transition:

```
$('#next').on('click', function () {
    $.mobile.changePage($('#child'), { transition : 'slide', reverse : true });
});
```

Here is the documentation for `$.mobile.changePage()`: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/docs/api/methods.html

If you wanted to roll your own transitions it's quite a bit more complex than showing one div and hiding another. You've got to setup some CSS classes that animate the transition using CSS3 (transform, transition, keyframes, etc.).

- And finally, here is a demo of your code where I replaced the links in the header with a single link that works: http://jsfiddle.net/MmKK4/

Comment: hurray done  but can u explain why my code was not working i m not able to understand properly what u have discuss above(why theme was not working at page 2)

Comment: @user1161898 There is a method in jQuery Mobile for showing a new page. And simply running the `.show()` function doesn't do it. For example, when you change to a new page, the jQuery Mobile framework initializes the page, if you try to manually show the page that initialization won't occur (**which is why your page is un-styled**). If you manually want to change the page, then use `$.mobile.changePage()` but also read the documentation on Page-Linking because all you really have to do is set the HREF attribute of a link to the ID of the pseudo-page you want to show, and the rest just happens.

Comment: $('#buttonid').click(function() {
       $.mobile.changePage($('#home'), { transition : 'slide', reverse : true });
});                 is not working

Comment: hi jasper but my code when i m runing it in mozilla is not working but working perfecrtly fine in jsfiddle.net

Comment: i m providing both to u  http://jsfiddle.net/khushbujoshi/Z2Lvs/2/     and other is  my blog where i have posted the same example as complete ready code in html u can use it & check in mozilla or any other browser   : http://errortec.blogspot.in/